# Convert one dictionary to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I need to convert one dictionary, whose values are in a list to a list of dictionaries.

For example, the following dictionary:

```
only_dict = {'First': [1, 2], 'Second': [3, 4]}
```

Should have the following output, where values are no longer in a list.

```
out_lst = [{'First': 1, 'Second': 3}, {'First': 2, 'Second': 4}]
```

Comment: what did you try

Comment: what are the requirements? how many keys may dict have? are there other facts you know aprior? what to do, if different keys have lists of non-equal sizes?

Comment: What should happen for this input `{'First': [1, 2], 'Second': [3, 4, 5]}`? And this one: `{'First': [1, 2], 'Second': [3, 4], 'Third': [5, 6]}`?

Comment: Value lists will always be the same length.

Comment: And so, the second option? `{'First': [1, 2], 'Second': [3, 4], 'Third': [5, 6]}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple version for any length of the lists. First, get the maximum list length:

```
count = max(*[len(x) for x in only_dict])
```

Construct each of the dictionaries one by one:

```
out_lst = [{k: v[i] for k, v in only_dict.items() if len(v) >= i} for i in range(count)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[{"First": v[0], "Second": v[1]} for v in only_dict.values()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generic version for lists of any length:

```
only_dict = {'First': [1,2,3], 'Second': [4,5,6], 'Third': [7,8,9]}
[dict(zip(only_dict, val)) for val in only_dict.values()]
```

output:

```
[{'First': 1, 'Second': 2, 'Third': 3},
 {'First': 4, 'Second': 5, 'Third': 6},
 {'First': 7, 'Second': 8, 'Third': 9}]
```

Comment: Isn't OP trying to achieve the opposite? Something like: `[dict(zip(only_dict, val)) for val in only_dict.values()]`

Comment: @SayandipDutta of course you're right thanks a lot, I guess my brain pushed it's own idea in between the time I read the question and typed the answer ^^ Anyway, the important part was to show `zip` here

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach to fill the list based on the total length of initial dictionary.

```
only_dict = {'First': [1, 2], 'Second': [3, 4]}
out_dict = {index: {} for index in range(len(only_dict.keys()))}
def fill(key, values):
    for index, val in enumerate(values):
        out_dict[index][key] = val
[fill(key, val) for key, val in only_dict.items()]
out_dict = list(out_dict.values())

print(out_dict)
```

Prints the output

```
[{'First': 1, 'Second': 3}, {'First': 2, 'Second': 4}]
```